# All attributes of these HTML5-elements

Tags: html, attributes, element

I have 4 HTML elements which I need to know its attributes (HTML5):
a - download, href, hreflang, media, rel, target, type
img - alt, crossorigin, height, ismap, longdesc, sizes, src, srcset, usemap, width
ol - reversed, start, type
td - headers, colspan, rowspan

Are there anymore?

Comment: Google? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a link of All tag supported by HTML5](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/)